# Convert Devexpress project from v17.2 to 21.2 (There is not DevExpress.ExpressApp.Images.dll anymore in v21.2 )

Tags: winforms, refactoring, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-blazor

I'm working on a project (Winforms app) that I want to convert the current project, `v17.2`, to `21.2`.
There is`DevExpress.ExpressApp.Images.v17.2.dll` in `v17.2` but there is not in `v21.2`.
How can handle this problem?
which `dll` can I replace instead?

Comment: See here for possible answer. https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t586496/updated-to-devexpress-web-v17-2-and-receiving-the-following-errors

Comment: @ourmandave: I visited that link but it was not useful at all.

Comment: Which class do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [The DevExpress.ExpressApp.Images assembly has been removed](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t974793/core-the-devexpress-expressapp-images-assembly-has-been-removed) you should reference the DevExpress.Images assembly. Also, I suggest you use the Project Converter tool that automatically updates existing DevExpress.ExpressApp.Images assembly references.